# Benford's Law in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to implement Benford's Law in R. So far, everything works accordingly, except that if there are some first-digits with 0 occurrences, an exception is thrown:

```
Error in data.frame(digit = 1:9, actual.count = first_digit_counts, actual.fraction = first_digit_counts/nrow(fraudDetection),  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 9, 5
```

This is because for my current data set, there are only first digits starting with 1, 2, 7, 8 and 9. How can I make it such that 3, 4, 5, 6 will have a count of 0 instead of not appearing at all in the table?

**Current Data Set:**

[image: Data Set]

This is the part that is causing the exception to be thrown:

```
first_digit_counts <- as.vector(table(fraudDetection$first.digit))
```

The current code in which this code fits in is as follows:

```
# load the required packages
require(reshape)
require(stringr)
require(plyr)
require(ggplot2)
require(scales)

# load in data from CSV file
fraudDetection <- read.csv("Fraud Case in Arizona 1993.csv")
names(fraudDetection)

# take only the columns containing the counts and manipulate the data into a "long" format with only one value per row
# let's try to compare the amount of the fraudulent transactions against the Benford's Law
fraudDetection <- melt(fraudDetection["Amount"])

# add columns containing the first and last digits, extracted using regular expressions
fraudDetection <- ddply(fraudDetection, .(variable), transform, first.digit = str_extract(value, "[123456789]"), last.digit  = str_extract(value, "[[:digit:]]$"))

# compare counts of each actual first digit against the counts predicted by Benford’s Law
first_digit_counts <- as.vector(table(fraudDetection$first.digit))
first_digit_actual_vs_expected <- data.frame(
digit            = 1:9,
actual.count     = first_digit_counts,    
actual.fraction  = first_digit_counts / nrow(fraudDetection),
benford.fraction = log10(1 + 1 / (1:9))
)
```

Comment: This is hard without an easily reproducible example. I think the answer might be to convert `first.digit` to a factor with levels 0-9.

Comment: Currently, the levels are as such, hence, there are several digits missing, resulting in a mismatch of rows.. Thinking how to perform factoring if the original output was already missing some digits.. Hmm..

`fraudDetection$first.digit
 [1] 1 2 8 7 8 9 9 8 8 9 7 8 9 9 8 9 9 8 9 8 9 8 7
Levels: 1 2 7 8 9`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to ensure that all digits are represented in `first_digit_counts`, you can convert `first.digit` to a factor, *explicitly setting the levels* so they include all digits from 1 to 9:

```
first_digit = c(1, 1, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9)
first_digit_factor = factor(first_digit, levels=1:9) # Explicitly set the levels
```

That makes your `table` calls perform as expected:

```
> table(first_digit)
first_digit
1 3 5 7 9 
2 1 3 4 1 
> table(first_digit_factor)
first_digit_factor
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
2 0 1 0 3 0 4 0 1 
> as.vector(table(first_digit_factor))
[1] 2 0 1 0 3 0 4 0 1
```

Answer (score 3):

A function for this is available from the `rattle` package

```
library(rattle)
dummy <- rnorm(100)
calcInitialDigitDistr(dummy, split = "none")
```

Answer (score 2):

Useful one line function

```
benford = function(x) barplot(table(as.numeric(substr(x,1,1))))

benford(ggplot2::diamonds$price)
```

[image]